# ExtJS TabItem Click Event

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc

Good Morning All,

I have an ExtJS 5 tabpanel. When the tabpanel first appears there is a single tab inside with a star for the title. What I need is when the user clicks the star for it to create a new tabItem. I have tried the activate event but that only works with more than one tab present. I have also tried binding to the a click event and nothing happens for that. Here is the code I have now:

```
{
                xtype:'tabpanel',
                itemId:'tabCtr1',
                width:785,
                items:[
                    { iconCls: 'btn-NewTab', html : 'A simple tab' }
                ]
            }

function assetDetailsDialog_AfterRender(sender, eOpts)
{
   parent.down('tabpanel').items.getAt(0).on('click', function(){
            alert('Hello World');
        });
}
```

Thanks everyone

**Follow On Issue:**

I am having one more issue with setting the active tab. When the button is click it creates the new tab not issue, but when I call setActiveTab it appears to do nothing. When I stepped through it in Chrome I can see it is actually changing the tab to the specified one but then switching it back to the original. Any help would be great. Any idea's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ln3) which demonstrates how to add tabs dynamically on click, the code is also listed below in case the link breaks. In the code below, the significant thing is adding the listener to the tabConfig

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            width: 800,
            height: 400,
            renderTo: document.body,
            items: [{
                title: 'Click me to add another tab',
                tabConfig: {
                    listeners: {
                        click: function(tab) {
                            alert("Adding another tab");
                            var newTab = tabPanel.add({
                                // we use the tabs.items property to get the length of current items/tabs
                                title: 'Tab ' + (tabPanel.items.length + 1),
                                html: 'Another one'
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                title: 'Bar',
                tabConfig: {
                    title: 'Custom Title',
                    tooltip: 'A button tooltip'
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Most of this code was taken from the documentation [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-items)

Comment: that worked like amazing. I googled it for going on an hour and could not find jack. That was exactly what I need.

One last question. Do you know how to add a context menu to the tab item title as well?

Comment: I haven't ever done it myself, so I dont know for sure. There is a built in plugin which adds a close context menu, you should be able to use that, see these links: http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/tabs/tabs-adv/viewer.html and http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.ux.TabCloseMenu

Comment: I am having one more issue with setting the active tab. When the button is click it creates the new tab not issue, but when I call setActiveTab it appears to do nothing. When I stepped through it in Chrome I can see it is actually changing the tab to the specified one but then switching it back to the original. Any help would be great. Any idea's?

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lnu) I could only get it  to work using a defer, so that it runs after the tab is fully rendered, you could probably add a listener to the dynamic tab that your creating, so on render it sets itself as the active tab